# Tomcat 7 and Apache2 connector can't get this working

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

First of all I put my app in tomcat7 as a ROOT so its like localhost:8080/

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
       connectionTimeout="20000"
       redirectPort="8443"
   URIEncoding="UTF-8"
/>
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" keystoreFile="/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/allegroTransaction.keystore" keystorePass="spec123ut"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />

<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Second is my apache2 config:

```
NameVirtualHost test.domian.com:80
Listen 80
<VirtualHost test.domian.com:80>

    ServerName test.domian.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/elo"

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/
    #ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

</VirtualHost>
```

And now the problem in error log I see:

> [Sun Apr 27 16:24:23 2014] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid
>   for the URL /. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure
>   the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using
>   LoadModule.

But everything look ok any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the following line in httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
```